# How to populate a python dictionary when keys are strings and values are lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, key

I need to create a dictionary as shown below:

```
d = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 6], 'c': [2, 5, 9]}
```

I have keys in the form of a list

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and values are present as separate lists

```
values = [[2, 3, 2], [3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 9]].
```

I've tried using

`d(zip(keys, values))`

but it returns a dictionary as

`{'a': [2, 3, 2], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': [4, 6, 9]}`

Is there any other method or correction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `zip` your `values` list before combining it with your keys:

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> values = [[2, 3, 2], [3, 4, 5], [4, 6, 9]]
>>> dict(zip(keys, zip(*values)))
{'a': (2, 3, 4), 'b': (3, 4, 6), 'c': (2, 5, 9)}
```

If the values **must be** lists (and not tuples), you can do the following:

```
>>> dict(zip(keys, map(list, zip(*values))))
{'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 6], 'c': [2, 5, 9]}
```